# 'ERROR 1290 (HY000)' inspite of commenting out the secure file priv section

Tags: mysql, import-from-csv

I am trying to load a csv file into a mysql table (Win 7). Below is the syntax I am using

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'path\continents.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE continents
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

In spite of following the instructions mentioned in stack overflow for the same problem (commenting out the **'Secure File Priv'** section in my configuration file and restarting the service), I am still getting this error.

Can someone help me with this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Linux?
Then it should rather be something like (forward slash and LOCAL):

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/continents.csv'
```

Comment: Ok, have you tried?
mysql> LOAD DATA *LOCAL* INFILE